# How to get result with specific fields in StrongLoop?

Tags: javascript, strongloop, loopbackjs

I am currently using StrongLoop as my API backend server and Mongodb as data storage engine.

Let's say there is a collection called `article`. It has two fields `title`, and `content`. And there are two frontend pages to display a list of articles and view a single article.

Obviously the data list page only need `title` field and the view page need both. Currently the `GET` method of StrongLoop API return all fields including `content`. It cost extra traffic. Is there any way that can just return specific field?

Mongodb support `projection` in `find()` method for this. How can I do the same thing by StrongLoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the filters offered. http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Querying+models

Answer (score 2):

**Query for NodeAPI:**

```
server.models.Student.findOne({where: {RFID: id},fields: {id: true,schoolId: true,classId: true}}, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) 
                         callback(err);
                         else {
                            callback();
                        }
                    })
```

**Query for RestAPI :**

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/services?filter[fields][id]=true&filter[fields][make]=true&filter[fields][model]=true')
                .then(function (response) {

                }, function (error) {

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fields projections,

Sample Record:

```
{ name: 'Something', title: 'mr', description: 'some desc', patient: { name: 'Asvf', age: 20, address: { street: 1 }}}
```

First Level Projection:

```
model.find({ fields: { name: 1, description: 1, title:  0 } })
```

and I think Strong loop is not yet supporting for second-level object filter, does anyone know how to filter second-level object properties or is yet to implement?.

Second Level Projection: (Need help here)

Ex: 2

```
model.find({ fields: { name: 1, 'patient.name': 1, 'patient.age': 1, 'patient.address': 0 } })
// Which results { name } only
```

Comment: Are you asking a question or providing a solution?

Comment: Actually both, the first example for the first level projection solution and Asking for the second-level projection (in Strongloop).  read the second example.